# Linq запрос в Html документ

Tags: c#, linq, xpath

Есть проблема с отбором id из html документа дела в том, что значение id меняется, но начало всегда одинаковое.

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id='Cars_(А здесь разное содержимое) ']");
```

Как мне одним linq запросом отобрать с веб-страницы все значения id? То есть мне нужно из строчки проведенной выше, только это `Cars_(А здесь разное содержимое)`.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то это совсем не linq запрос, а вроде как XQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию XPath [starts-with()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[starts-with(@id, 'Cars_']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут лучше всего использовать CSS Selector, другого пути я не вижу. Могу посоветовать [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/). Это лучшее, что можно сделать в данном вопросе.